# rpm used before to install/upgrade packages - would now want to use yum instead

Tags: yum, rpm

Someone was performing an upgrade of a software running on our RHEL Server with `rpm -Uvh package_name.rpm`

I'd like to use `yum -U package_name.rpm`

Can this cause any problem or inconsistency?

Comment: You might get better results using "yum install" for the package-files.  It will do an update as needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to update specific packages with `yum` then the correct command is:

```
yum update package.rpm
```

Of course, an important thing to note is exactly how the packages were installed and whether or not there are updates in the repos that `yum` will use. If you can't confirm that the `--nodeps` switch wasn't used then you may run into dependency issues at runtime when using the packages.

A better thing to do is to just use `yum` to install the packages as it will pull the latest version along with dependencies.

Comment: Thank you but I'm a bit puzzled. I think RPM does not resolve dependencies (it only reports them) so if there weren't any why would / could I possibly run into dependency issues? Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: @blablatrace What I'm saying is that whoever was doing the upgrades could have used the `--nodeps` switch with `rpm` and missed dependencies. Using `yum` will pull the dependencies as necessary. I've updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you again. So with the --nodeps options the warning aout dependencies is not even logged and rpm continues to install the given rpm package, yes?

Comment: @blablatrace As `rpm` doesn't even keep a log for installation actions, that is correct. The only way to know if it was performed with the `--nodeps` switch and the dependencies weren't installed is if they error at runtime regarding missing libraries. Personally, I don't know why whomever installed them chose to use `rpm` instead of `yum` because it would have been necessary to download and install them in the correct order one by one to avoid dependency issues. That's why it's better to use `yum` to install software.

Answer (score 2):

no, `yum` uses `rpm` underneath. The only important difference is that `yum` knows about *repositories* and can thus - if needed - decide to fetch packages from those repositories to install. `rpm` does not, and will thus only install what you provide him.

Note: the `yum` syntax is different from `rpm`:

- to install a new package, use `yum install package`
- to update a package to a new version; use `yum update package`
- to update all packages; use `yum update`